# Appending two text lines if the second line starts with a particular word

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider a .txt file with the following content:

```
Pinus ponderosa P. & C. Lawson
var. scopulorum Engelm.
[5,800] - [7,800] 9,200 ft. [May] - [Jun]. Needleleaf
evergreen tree, mesophanerophyte; nanophyll, sclerophyll.
```

I would like to append any line starting with `var.` to the previous line.

Here's my code:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = ''
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace('\n', '')
        if next(f)[:4] == 'var.':
            txt = '{}\n{} {}'.format(txt, line, next(f))
```

This throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module> StopIteration
```

The expected output is:

```
Pinus ponderosa P. & C. Lawson var. scopulorum Engelm.
[5,800] - [7,800] 9,200 ft. [May] - [Jun]. Needleleaf
evergreen tree, mesophanerophyte; nanophyll, sclerophyll.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one shot instead of iterating over the lines. Also if you wanted edit the file:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()

txt = txt.replace('\nvar.', ' var.')

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(txt)
```

Comment: you might want to replace with '[blank]var.' so that there is a separation with the previous line

Comment: The `\n` sequence are at the end of the lines, not at the beginning

Comment: @Junitar the file is read in a single piece, so this works. The line break only makes a difference if you are using readlines

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    txt = ''
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('var.'):  #Use str.startswith
            txt += " " + line
        else:
            txt += "\n" + line

print(txt.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Pinus ponderosa P. & C. Lawson var. scopulorum Engelm.
[5,800] - [7,800] 9,200 ft. [May] - [Jun]. Needleleaf
evergreen tree, mesophanerophyte; nanophyll, sclerophyll.
```

Comment: It works well but is there a way to do this using the `''.format()` structure?

Comment: sorry i do not understand? did you mean `txt += "\n{}".format(line)` or `txt += " {}".format(line)`?